# Kerberos and yarn nodemanager fail to connecting resourcemanager. Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, kerberos

I`m trying to run my cluster with Kerberos. Before hdfs, yarn and spark worked correctly. After setting up kerberos, I can only run hdfs because yarn is going to crush after 15 minutes with an error. I have tried different configurations with no result.
Master node do not have any logs about slave node. Nodemanager run just for 15 minutes but **do not show on yarn master list.**

I do not understand why you can use kinit or hdfs run with no problem, but yarn seems to not connect the resource manager.

**Log:**

```
[...]
2020-12-02 22:23:07,532 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Started ServerConnector@333cb916{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8042}
2020-12-02 22:23:07,532 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server: Started @3804ms
2020-12-02 22:23:07,532 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps: Web app node started at 8042
2020-12-02 22:23:07,534 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Node ID assigned is : node1:46673
2020-12-02 22:23:07,537 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.JvmPauseMonitor: Starting JVM pause monitor
2020-12-02 22:23:07,541 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.DefaultNoHARMFailoverProxyProvider: Connecting to ResourceManager at master.ar.com/192.168.46.100:8031
2020-12-02 22:23:07,567 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Sending out 0 NM container statuses: []
2020-12-02 22:23:07,576 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Registering with RM using containers :[]
2020-12-02 22:33:05,974 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Cache Size Before Clean: 0, Total Deleted: 0, Public Deleted: 0, Private Deleted: 0
2020-12-02 22:38:07,867 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Unexpected error starting NodeStatusUpdater
java.io.IOException: DestHost:destPort master.ar.com:8031 , LocalHost:localPort node1.ar.com/192.168.46.101:0. Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Couldn't set up IO streams: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor23.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:837)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:812)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1566)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1508)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1405)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:234)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:119)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76.registerNodeManager(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.api.impl.pb.client.ResourceTrackerPBClientImpl.registerNodeManager(ResourceTrackerPBClientImpl.java:74)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy77.registerNodeManager(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.registerWithRM(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:416)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.serviceStart(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:274)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeService.java:122)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:963)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:1042)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't set up IO streams: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:884)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$3800(Client.java:413)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1636)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1452)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.getServerPrincipal(SaslRpcClient.java:333)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.createSaslClient(SaslRpcClient.java:240)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.selectSaslClient(SaslRpcClient.java:166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.saslConnect(SaslRpcClient.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupSaslConnection(Client.java:622)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2300(Client.java:413)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:822)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:818)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1845)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:818)
        ... 24 more
2020-12-02 22:38:07,870 INFO org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: Service org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl failed in state STARTED
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.io.IOException: DestHost:destPort master.ar.com:8031 , LocalHost:localPort node1.ar.com/192.168.46.101:0. Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Couldn't set up IO streams: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.serviceStart(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:280)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeService.java:122)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:963)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:1042)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: DestHost:destPort master.ar.com:8031 , LocalHost:localPort node1.ar.com/192.168.46.101:0. Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Couldn't set up IO streams: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor23.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:837)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:812)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1566)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1508)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1405)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:234)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:119)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76.registerNodeManager(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.api.impl.pb.client.ResourceTrackerPBClientImpl.registerNodeManager(ResourceTrackerPBClientImpl.java:74)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy77.registerNodeManager(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.registerWithRM(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:416)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.serviceStart(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:274)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't set up IO streams: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:884)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$3800(Client.java:413)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1636)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1452)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.getServerPrincipal(SaslRpcClient.java:333)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.createSaslClient(SaslRpcClient.java:240)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.selectSaslClient(SaslRpcClient.java:166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.saslConnect(SaslRpcClient.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupSaslConnection(Client.java:622)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2300(Client.java:413)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:822)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:818)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1845)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:818)
        ... 24 more
2020-12-02 22:38:07,871 INFO org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: Service NodeManager failed in state STARTED
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.io.IOException: DestHost:destPort master.ar.com:8031 , LocalHost:localPort node1.ar.com/192.168.46.101:0. Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Couldn't set up IO streams: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.serviceStart(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:280)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeService.java:122)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:963)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:1042)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: DestHost:destPort master.ar.com:8031 , LocalHost:localPort node1.ar.com/192.168.46.101:0. Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Couldn't set up IO streams: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor23.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:837)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:812)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1566)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1508)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1405)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:234)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:119)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76.registerNodeManager(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.api.impl.pb.client.ResourceTrackerPBClientImpl.registerNodeManager(ResourceTrackerPBClientImpl.java:74)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy77.registerNodeManager(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.registerWithRM(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:416)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.serviceStart(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:274)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't set up IO streams: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:884)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$3800(Client.java:413)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1636)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1452)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.getServerPrincipal(SaslRpcClient.java:333)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.createSaslClient(SaslRpcClient.java:240)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.selectSaslClient(SaslRpcClient.java:166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.saslConnect(SaslRpcClient.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupSaslConnection(Client.java:622)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2300(Client.java:413)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:822)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:818)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1845)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:818)
        ... 24 more
2020-12-02 22:38:07,877 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@6fa02932{node,/,null,UNAVAILABLE}{jar:file:/home/hadoop/hadoop-3.3.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-3.3.0.jar!/webapps/node}
2020-12-02 22:38:07,880 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Stopped ServerConnector@333cb916{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8042}
2020-12-02 22:38:07,880 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.session: node0 Stopped scavenging
2020-12-02 22:38:07,881 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@aac3f4e{static,/static,jar:file:/home/hadoop/hadoop-3.3.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-3.3.0.jar!/webapps/static,UNAVAILABLE}
2020-12-02 22:38:07,881 INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2b4786dd{logs,/logs,file:///home/hadoop/hadoop-3.3.0/logs/,UNAVAILABLE}
2020-12-02 22:38:07,884 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping server on 46673
2020-12-02 22:38:07,895 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server listener on 0
2020-12-02 22:38:07,895 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server Responder
2020-12-02 22:38:07,896 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl is interrupted. Exiting.
2020-12-02 22:38:07,911 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping server on 8040
2020-12-02 22:38:07,912 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server listener on 8040
2020-12-02 22:38:07,915 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server Responder
2020-12-02 22:38:07,916 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Public cache exiting
2020-12-02 22:38:07,917 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeResourceMonitorImpl: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeResourceMonitorImpl is interrupted. Exiting.
2020-12-02 22:38:07,920 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping NodeManager metrics system...
2020-12-02 22:38:07,921 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NodeManager metrics system stopped.
2020-12-02 22:38:07,921 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NodeManager metrics system shutdown complete.
2020-12-02 22:38:07,921 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: Error starting NodeManager
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.io.IOException: DestHost:destPort master.ar.com:8031 , LocalHost:localPort node1.ar.com/192.168.46.101:0. Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Couldn't set up IO streams: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.serviceStart(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:280)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeService.java:122)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:963)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:1042)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: DestHost:destPort master.ar.com:8031 , LocalHost:localPort node1.ar.com/192.168.46.101:0. Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Couldn't set up IO streams: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor23.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:837)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:812)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1566)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1508)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1405)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:234)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:119)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76.registerNodeManager(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.api.impl.pb.client.ResourceTrackerPBClientImpl.registerNodeManager(ResourceTrackerPBClientImpl.java:74)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy77.registerNodeManager(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.registerWithRM(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:416)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.serviceStart(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:274)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't set up IO streams: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:884)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$3800(Client.java:413)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1636)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1452)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.getServerPrincipal(SaslRpcClient.java:333)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.createSaslClient(SaslRpcClient.java:240)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.selectSaslClient(SaslRpcClient.java:166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.saslConnect(SaslRpcClient.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupSaslConnection(Client.java:622)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2300(Client.java:413)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:822)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:818)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1845)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:818)
        ... 24 more
2020-12-02 22:38:07,926 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NodeManager at node1.ar.com/192.168.46.101
************************************************************/
```

**core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
            <name>fs.default.name</name>
            <value>hdfs://master.ar.com:9000</value>
        </property>

<property>
 <name>hadoop.security.authentication</name>
 <value>kerberos</value>
</property>

<property>
 <name>hadoop.security.authorization</name>
 <value>true</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<configuration>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
        <value>/home/hadoop/hdfs/namenode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
        <value>/home/hadoop/hdfs/datanode</value>
    </property>


<property>
 <name>dfs.block.access.token.enable</name>
 <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
 <name>dfs.client.read.shortcircuit</name>
 <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
 <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir.perm</name>
 <value>700</value>
</property>

<property>
 <name>dfs.datanode.address</name>
 <value>0.0.0.0:1004</value>
</property>

<property>
 <name>dfs.datanode.http.address</name>
 <value>0.0.0.0:1006</value>
</property>

<property>
 <name>dfs.datanode.kerberos.principal</name>
 <value>hdfs/node1.ar.com@AR.COM</value>
</property>

<property>
 <name>dfs.datanode.kerberos.http.principal</name>
 <value>HTTP/node1.ar.com@AR.COM</value>
</property>

<property>
 <name>dfs.datanode.keytab.file</name>
 <value>/etc/security/keytab/hdfs.service.keytab</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

**yarn-site.xml**

```
<configuration>

<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>master.ar.com</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
    </property>


<property>
 <name>yarn.nodemanager.principal</name>
 <value>yarn/node1.ar.com@AR.COM</value>
</property>

<property>
 <name>yarn.nodemanager.keytab</name>
 <value>/etc/security/keytab/yarn.service.keytab</value>
</property>

<property>
 <name>yarn.nodemanager.container-executor.class</name>
 <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor</value>
</property>

<property>
 <name>yarn.nodemanager.linux-container-executor.group</name>
 <value>yarn</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing `yarn.resourcemanager.principal`. Try adding below configuration on NodeManager's yarn-site.xml.

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.principal</name>
  <value>yarn/master.ar.com@AR.COM</value>
</property>
```